# Normaliz undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'

Tags: c++, macos, boost, compiler-errors, linkage

I'm trying to install the library [Normaliz](https://github.com/Normaliz/Normaliz) having dependencies like [CocoALib](http://cocoa.dima.unige.it/cocoalib/), [SCIP](http://scip.zib.de/). I've made its dependencies according to their guidances. However, I get the error while `make` of Normaliz on both Ubuntu and Mac OSX,

```
[ 81%] Linking CXX executable normaliz

libnormaliz/libnormaliz.so.3.4.0: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
libnormaliz/libnormaliz.so.3.4.0: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/normaliz.dir/build.make:99: recipe for target 'normaliz' failed
make[2]: *** [normaliz] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:99: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/normaliz.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/normaliz.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I really fed up with it since two weeks! How can it be overcome?

Even if it is boost linkage problem, how can it be linked? There is no option for it. *That kinda headaches cause apathy to open-source at least for young programmers like me.* 
[image]

Comment: Link with the `boost_system` library?

Comment: Edited question @Someprogrammerdude